# How to store the app status inside the phone

Tags: ios

hi I want to do something like this. My application has a registration process. When user enter their phone number in registration page and click the registration then user get a PIN number as a SMS. Also user redirect to the PIN verification `ViewController`.

What I want to do is keep the user current status in the application. That means if user type the phone number and after getting the SMS without entering the PIN number to veryfi he can close the app. So next time when he open the app it should load the Verification `ViewController`. In order to do that I have to keep the status of the app inside my phone.

How I can store this. Can I use `KeychainItemWrapper` for this? If so can I make several `KeychainItems` by changing the identifire name.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Will it store after the app close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSUserDefaults is the easiest way to go:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
```

And to retrieve:

```
     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *firstName = [defaults objectForKey:@"firstName"];
```

And yes, it will stay after the app is closed.

Comment: How can keep one user default through out the whole application. I mean I want to add several status at many Viewcontrollers. As an example in Verification viewcontroller I want to keep the status as verify, in login viewcontroller it should be update as Logged likewise

Comment: Just use the same key, and change the value of it.

Comment: when I put  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; Its not going to create a new object each and every time?

Comment: No, it's the same object all the time, it's a singleton

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ...

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *registrationStatus;
    if (![defaults objectForKey@"registrationStatus"])
      registrationStatus = @"notRegistered";
    else
      registrationStatus = [defaults objectForKey@"registrationStatus"];


    if ([registrationStatus isEqualToString:@"notRegistered"]) {
        // show registration form

        // When sending the SMS, you store the current status in NSUserDefaults like this
        // [defaults setObject:@"registeredButNotValidated" forKey:@"registrationStatus"];
        // [defaults synchronize];
    } else if ([registrationStatus isEqualToString:@"registeredButNotValidated"]) {
        // show validation form

        // When validated, you store the current status in NSUserDefaults like this
        // [defaults setObject:@"registered" forKey:@"registrationStatus"];
        // [defaults synchronize];
    } else {
        // registered
    }

    return YES;
}
```